# Generar números aleatorios sin que se repitan y luego se guarde dentro de una variable

Tags: java, bucle-for, vectores

Esto es lo que pude hacer, pero no sé cómo hacer que los números aleatorios no se repitan, además de tampoco saber cómo hacer que se guarden en una variable.

````
         int contador = 0;

               int numeros [] = new int [5];

                 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                   i = contador;
                   contador++; 
                     aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                     System.out.println("[" + aleatorio + "]");    
                 } 
                     System.out.println(""); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

todo ello puedes hacerlo usando la clase [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) junto con el metodo [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)

Ejemplo

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Prueba{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
     int [] numeros=new Random().ints(1, 100).distinct().limit(5).toArray();

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
}
}
```

`ints()`    Devuelve un flujo efectivamente ilimitado de int valores pseudoaleatorios.

`distinct()` Devuelve un flujo que consta de los distintos elementos

`limit()` limita los valores

`toArray()` convierte en array

salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]